# Join 2 integers (integral and decimal part) to a double in C#

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
int integralPart = 123;
int decimalPart = 12345;
// double desiredDouble = 123.12345;
```

I would like to create a double from 2 ints, as shown in the example.

I know I can use `double.Parse(integralPart.ToString() + "." + decimalPart.ToString())`, but I am getting some exceptions if the application isn't using English as default language.

Comment: How would you represent `123.01234` with 2 ints?

Comment: One int is the decimal part.

Comment: Would you really want (123, 45) to be equal to (123, 450)? It sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: @Pacha: You've missed Jacob's point. What's the difference between (123, 1234) and (123, 01234) and (123, 001234)?

Comment: There is ambiguity here:  Consider: `decimalPart = 12;`.  Do you want the output to be `0.12`, or `0.000012`?  They both have a decimalPart 12!

Comment: Yes, I got it now. It won't be a problem as they are prices, and the first digit will never be zero.

Comment: @Pacha: they are prices? Then don't use a double. Do everything in cents with integer arithmetic.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I am working with some code someone made before me, and he used doubles for everything (maybe because the database uses doubles as well). I don't want to fix it as I have to finish this quickly.

Comment: @Pacha: in that case: stay calm and slowly walk away from the project ... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your wording alone, I'd suggest you really wanted to use `decimal`s:

```
int integralPart = 123;
int decimalPart = 12345;

decimal result = decimalPart;
while (result>=1m) result/=10m; // CAVEAT: see below

result+=integralPart;
```

Oops. And there is the big ambiguity problem others have mentioned. Likely, you'd need to replace my `while` with a fixed scale:

```
result = integralPart + decimalPart / 1000000m; // fixed scale factor
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems the best solution

Answer (score 2):

A fix to your solution:

```
double.Parse(integralPart.ToString() + "." + decimalPart.ToString(),
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's not very efficient, though.

If they are prices, use `decimal` instead:

```
decimal.Parse(integralPart.ToString() + "." + decimalPart.ToString(),
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```